# Are tabs and Fragment menus incompatible in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

TLDR: Adding menu items for a fragment causes onTabSelected to be called infinitely.

---

I am working on an app for Android 4.0+ and have run into a problem. I am currently using an `ActionBar` with tabs, which works well. When I click a tab, the method `onTabSelected(Tab, FragmentTransaction)` is called once, and I switch the fragments that are shown on screen. Here is the method:

```
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    onTabSelected(tab, ft);

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    switch(tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0 :
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.buttons_box, ButtonsFragment.newInstance(0))
                .commit();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, ControlsFragment.newInstance(0))
                .commit();
            break;
        case 1 :
        ...
        case 2 :
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I want to add menu items for the fragment. In `ControlsFragment`, I add the following methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.controls, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.control_1 :
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked Control 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
        default :
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

And added this line in `onCreate(Bundle)`:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Only now, when the app is run, the first tab is selected by default, and the method `onTabSelected` in my Activity is called over and over again. Why does this occur? Are tabs and fragment menu items incompatible?

**EDIT**

I tried removing the call to `onTabSelected` from `onTabReselected`, but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: They should not be incompatible. What implementation of the action bar (native API Level 11? AppCompat? ActionBarSherlock?) and fragments (native API Level 11? Android Support backport?) are you using? BTW, is there a reason you are using two `FragmentTransactions` instead of one?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using native everything - API 14+. As for the two `FragmentTransactions` - I have not used `Fragment`s much, and am not fully familiar with how it works. Would you recommend just adding the `replace` line from the second transaction to the first transaction?

Comment: "Would you recommend just adding the replace line from the second transaction to the first transaction?" -- it would be a bit more efficient. It's conceivable that it might even help with your problem, though that would surprise me. Then again, the problem itself surprises me.

Comment: @CommonsWare I made the change - but unfortunately it still works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This was causing all sorts of issues, so I found a simple work-around. This simple hack fixes the strange issue.

1. Create a variable:

   ```
   private Tab currentTab;
   ```
2. Add the following lines at the top of `onTabSelected`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
       if (currentTab == null)
           currentTab = tab;
       else if (currentTab == tab)
           return;
       else
           currentTab = tab;
       //your code here
   }
   ```